# package.json script for React Component quick creation

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, yarnpkg

Is it possible to write a **script** in package.json that will create a new directory with name passed as argument '`MyComponent`' (for example) and will create four files with the same name:

1. MyComponent.js
2. MyComponent.css
3. MyComponent.test.js
4. README.md

---

```
"scripts": {
  "new_comp": "..."
}
```

Simple usage:

> $ yarn (npm run) new_comp --MyComponent

-> new dir 'MyComponent' with four specified files created

*The directory should be created in my current directory (not in the root where is located package.json)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this can be a native npm command callable directly from package.js's script.
But it is of course possible to write a javascript script file and call it from yarn. You just have to create the script that will actually create your folder and its content.

**package.json**

```
...
"scripts": {
    ...
    "babelnode": "node node_modules/babel-cli/bin/babel-node",
    "new_comp": "yarn babelnode ./src/scripts/createComponent.js",
    ...
}
...
```

**createComponent.js**

```
import fs from 'fs';

const dir = process.argv[2];
if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
    fs.mkdirSync(dir);
}
fs.writeFileSync(path.join(dir,`${dir}.js`), '');
fs.writeFileSync(path.join(dir,`${dir}.css`), '');
fs.writeFileSync(path.join(dir,`${dir}.test.js`), '');
fs.writeFileSync(path.join(dir,'README.MD'), '');
```

**command line**

`yarn new_comp MyComponent`

The question was "is it possible" so this is untested but should get you started.

**Notes:**

I've used babel-node to be able to write the script in es6.

[babel-node](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-node)

If you don't use it the "MyComponent" argument may not be in index 2 of `process.argv`

**References:**

[nodejs - fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)

[babel CLI](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli)

Comment: Thank you for the proposed solution. I also managed to write something like your solution, but I would like it to be without dependencies on other files. It would be desirable that it were simply instructions of a command line like mkdir and touch / echo

Comment: If you do it only with shell command line then you will be relying on the shell you're expecting to interpret your command. If you do know which shell will be involved, I suggest that you post a new question for this particular shell.